# How to use INTERSECT together with COUNT in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, inner-join, intersect

I have a table called *customer_transactions* and a table called *blacklist*.
The *customer_transactions* table has a column called *atm_name*.
Both tables share a unique key called *id*.

How can I intersect the two tables in such a way that the query shows me

1. customers that appear on both tables.
2. a corresponding column that displays the times that they had used a
   certain atm alongside the atm's name
   (for instance: id_1 -- bank of america -- 2; id_1 -- citibank -- 3;
   id_2 -- bank of america -- 1; id_2 -- citibank -- 4, etcetera).

I have something like this

```
SELECT id,
atm_name,
count(atm_name) as atm_count 
FROM customer_transactions 
GROUP BY id, atm_name
```

How can I INTERSECT this table with the *blacklist* table and maintain what I currently have as output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a join. Assuming that column `id` relates the two tables, and that it is a unique key in `blacklist`, you can do:

```
select ct.id, ct.atm_name, count(*) as atm_count 
from customer_transactions ct
inner join blacklist b on b.id = ct.id
group by ct.id, ct.atm_name
```

You can also express this logic with `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select ct.id, ct.atm_name, count(*) as atm_count 
from customer_transactions ct
where exists (select 1  from blacklist b where b.id = ct.id)
group by ct.id, ct.atm_name
```

Comment: worked like a charm. i was playing with the except/intersect operators all day long and i 
was stuck in a loop (beginner issues). thank you very much.